# Tkinter - Custom items in a TreeView widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two simple questions about the `TreeView` widget:

1. how can I change the background of an item placed in my `TreeView` widget?
2. when I select my custom item (see the point one), it doesn't be highlighted. how can I reach my goal?

I attached a screenshot to make it easy to understand what I wanna do:

[image]

below code example, it's a simple `TreeView` widget, how can I apply the right changed to reach my goal?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, height=15)

tree.insert("" , 0, "Menu0",text="Item 1")
tree.insert("Menu0", 0, "Menu0-0",text="1")
tree.insert("Menu0", 1, "Menu0-1",text="2")

tree.insert("", 1, "Menu1", text="Item 2")
tree.insert("Menu1", 0, "Menu1-0", text="1")
tree.insert("Menu1", 1, "Menu1-1", text="2")

tree.insert("", 2, "Menu2", text="Item 3")
tree.insert("Menu2", 0, "Menu2-0", text="1")
tree.insert("Menu2", 1, "Menu2-1", text="2")

tree.insert("", 3, "Menu3", text="Item 4")
tree.insert("Menu3", 0, "Menu3-0", text="1")


tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could run it and test some ideas.

Comment: @furas: ciao furas, I just added my code, but it's just a simple tree. from here on out, I don't know how to move forward.

Comment: to set background color you can add tag `tree.insert("" , ...., tags='main_item')` and configure tag `tree.tag_configure('main_item', background='cyan')`. But item changes color when you select it. There is no option to set selection color. Maybe it will need events but I didn't found method for this.

Comment: @furas: I just added these two instructions but the color for the "item 1" didn't change: `tree.insert("" , 0, "Menu0",text="Item 1", tags='main_item')` and `tree.tag_configure('main_item', background='cyan')`

Comment: it may also depends on system - they may use native widgets which may not have this functionality. It works on Linux but I don't know if it works on Windows or Mac.

Comment: @furas: I tried the code in Linux and Mac, and with them it works (the "item 1" color appears) but in Windows 10 it doesn't. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: you can check if this will works for you `style = ttk.Style()` and `style.configure('Treeview', background='red')` and `style.map('Treeview', background=[('focus', 'green')])` but it changes colors for all elements. But if this doesn't change colors on Windows then may not be method to change color - simply Windows native widgets may not gives access to these values. And then maybe you should use other GUI - ie. PyQt